# Xcode: is it possible to  save uiwebview in core data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, uiwebview, save

I have an application which receives data from a news website (through rss) and puts articles in a tableview. User can select an article from the list to view the detail on a webview. On the detail view user can click on a button to save data in the database.

I'm able to save articles and show them in "favourites" table view but the problem is that for now i'm saving and using the link to the article and loading it when user selects a saved article. While i want to save article and allow user to read it in offline mode. I'm using core data. Is there a way to save the whole webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a news web site you can typically get an RSS feed with **all** the data to reconstruct a complete news story, i.e. with a subject, a category, the complete article text, etc., including even links to images.

Just retrieve these feeds, parse into your `NSManagedObject` properties and store them in Core Data as usual.

That being said, many sites do not allow the news to be displayed without links to their web site, some even insist you read the article on the web site. You will need to read the fine print.

Comment: that's exactly what i'm doing but again the links (for images for exp)  will need an internet connection while i want to save and open an article in offline mode.

Comment: Well, just save the images in the user's documents directory by giving them a unique name (e.g. with the message id in the file name) and pull them from there. That's what I do in one of my apps. I check if this "cache" is not too large each time and delete files if it gets too big. Alternatively you can add them the the core data store.